# How do I use data values as attribute values in datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have this piece of code with its data in JSON ( converted from database) and I want the **data-id**  and **id** attributes value to come from the JSON data using **JQuery DataTables**.

1. The code below works without errors but i want to replace the `data[0].id` with the iteration (something like `data[i].id`)

**code**

```
 $('#example_senderid').dataTable({

            data:  data,
            columns: [
            {'data':'user_id'},
            {'data':'name'},
            {'data':'status'},
            {'data':'date_added'},
            {'defaultContent':"<button data-id='"+data[0].id+"' class='editConfirm'><span class='fa fa-pencil'></span>Edit</button>"}
            ],
  'columnDefs': [
     {
        'targets':[1,2],
        'createdCell':  function (td,) {
           $(td).attr('id', 'editSenderConfirm'+data[0].id); 
        }
     }
  ]


          });
```

2. I have tried point 1. but did not work.

I am hoping there is a way to do it with the DataTable itself.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It is really not very clear what you are asking for.

Comment: I want to use the set HTML attribute values eg. data-id="2". But the values to come from data.id or data.user_id

Comment: See https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback and https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render or a dozen SO answers.

Comment: Renders solved my problem. Thanks